# Loading Icon on Ajax Postback in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is my first php project. I have imlemented partial ajax postback by refering to this article:   [PHP AJAX SQL reference article](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp)

Now, I am trying to show a loading gif when the partial loading starts and hide it when the partial loading completes. Here is the code that I am using in Javascript:

```
function showUser1(str) 
    {
        if (str == "") 
        {
            document.getElementById("mems").innerHTML = "I caanot fetch: " + str;
            return;
        }
        else 
        { 
            document.getElementById("loadgif").style.visibility= "visible";
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
            {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else 
            {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
                {
                    document.getElementById("outerpicwrapper").innerHTML = "";
                    document.getElementById("mems").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET","getmembers.php?q2="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            document.getElementById("loadgif").style.visibility= "hidden";
        }
    }
```

In the first line of body, I have written:

```
<img id="loadgif" src="img/loading.gif" class="loadinggif" />
```

In the CSS file, i have written:

```
.loadinggif
{
position: absolute;
z-index: 200;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

The code is working fine and shows the data but, loading gif is not shown.
I have even tried display:none and display:block in place of visibility.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is AJAX is asynchronous. Thus your code doesn't wait for the data to be fetched and

```
 document.getElementById("loadgif").style.visibility= "visible";
 document.getElementById("loadgif").style.visibility= "hidden";
```

### These lines are executed simultaneously.

To prevent this from happening you can put

```
document.getElementById("loadgif").style.visibility= "hidden";
```

inside the callback as well

```
function showUser1(str) 
{
    if (str == "") 
    {
        document.getElementById("mems").innerHTML = "I caanot fetch: " + str;
        return;
    }
    else 
    { 
        document.getElementById("loadgif").style.visibility= "visible"; // This line displays the loading gif
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
        {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else 
        {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
            {
                document.getElementById("outerpicwrapper").innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById("mems").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                document.getElementById("loadgif").style.visibility= "hidden"; // This line hides the loading gif
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getmembers.php?q2="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. I have tried putting that code as you specified. But still, i cannot see the loading gif anywhere on my page. In your solution, which line will make the loading gif visible?

Comment: I have commented beside the lines which should display and hide the loading-gif respectively. What is the error you are getting? Go to your browser's console and tell me if there are any errors.

Comment: There is no error neither there is any gif display. Only data is getting fetched and shown.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the data is being fetched so fast that the loading gif is hidden before you can see it?

Comment: well, data was taking time to be fetched. However, I have solved the issue myself through JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I made my issue work out using JQuery.
I just made display:none in CSS and called the show() function of jquery on the loading gif div. This show function was written inside the javascript code.